# Sparse Matrix vector product in Fortran

Tags: matrix, vector, fortran, sparse-matrix

How can I do a matrix-vector multiplication in Fortran, knowing that my matrix is sparse?

For example I want to compute the product between the 3x3 matrix

```
0 1 2
3 0 0
4 0 5
```

and the vector

```
1
2
3
```

I was thinking about storing the the row and columns as well as the value when it's not equal to zero but it didn't get me anywhere.

Comment: I'll just comment that Fortran 77 has been obsolete for 30 years now - if you wish to do this why use it when better tools are readily available?

Comment: Because it's my 1st year doing Fortran in Class and they want us to learn it from the bottom. We'll be using Fortran 95 later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you will need to decide whether sparse or dense algebra will be faster:

- what is the matrix size being involved in the actual calculation? if it is some `dimension(m,n)`, where, say, `m<=10` and `n<=10`, then, using dense algebra will be faster anyways: `matmul(A,b)` or another library implementation of matrix-vector multiplication will do the job.
- What is the sparsity level of your matrix? In your example, the matrix is some ~44% sparse (`sparsity=count(matrix==0)/product(shape(matrix))`) Usually, if the matrix is at least some 50% sparse, using sparse algebra will be beneficial over dense algebra.

Once you decide to use sparse algebra, do not define your own sparse matrix storage! Just use one of the [plenty available out there](http://netlib.org/linalg/html_templates/node90.html). If matrix-vector multiplication is most you have to do with sparse matrices, I would go with `CSR`. Some simple implementation would look like:

```
module sparse_CSR
  use iso_fortran_env
  implicit none
  public

    type, public :: CSRMatrix
       integer :: m = 0
       integer :: n = 0
       integer, allocatable :: rowPtr(:)
       integer, allocatable :: colPtr(:)
       real(real64), allocatable :: aij(:)
    end type CSRMatrix 
    
    contains
    
    ! Convert a dense matrix to a sparse one. 
    pure type(CSRMatrix) function dense_to_sparse(matrix) result(sparse)
       real(real64), intent(in) :: matrix(:,:)

       integer :: ierr,m,n,nnz,row,nnz_row,j1,j2,colIndex(size(matrix,2))
       logical :: row_nonZeroes(size(matrix,2))

       ! Get matrix size
       m = size(matrix,1)
       n = size(matrix,2)
       nnz = count(matrix/=0.0_real64)

       ! Create an array of indices
       forall(j1=1:n) colIndex(j1) = j1

       ! Set matrix size
       sparse%m = m
       sparse%n = n
       
       ! Allocate data
       allocate(sparse%rowPtr(m+1),sparse%colPtr(nnz),sparse%aij(nnz))

       ! Fill rows
       sparse%rowPtr(1) = 1
       fill_by_rows: do row=1,m
          row_nonZeroes = matrix(row,:)/=0.d0      
          nnz_row = count(row_nonZeroes)
          
          j1 = sparse%rowPtr(row)
          j2 = j1+nnz_row-1
          sparse%colPtr(j1:j2) = pack(colIndex     ,row_nonZeroes)
          sparse%aij   (j1:j2) = pack(matrix(row,:),row_nonZeroes)

          ! Set pointer for beginning of next line
          sparse%rowPtr(row+1) = j2+1
     
       end do fill_by_rows

    end function dense_to_sparse
     
    ! Compute matrix-vector product
    pure function sparse_matvec(matrix,vector) result(MxV)
       type(CSRMatrix), intent(in) :: matrix
       real(real64), intent(in) :: vector(:)
       real(real64) :: MxV(matrix%m)

       integer :: row,j,j1,j2,col
       real(real64) :: aij

       ! Check size. Cannot stop in a pure procedure. 
       ! So, return NaNs
       if (size(vector,1)/=matrix%n) then 
          MxV(:) = transfer(-2251799813685248_int64, 1._real64)
          return
       endif  

       ! Compute product by rows
       do row=1,matrix%m
          j1 = matrix%rowPtr(row)
          j2 = matrix%rowPtr(row+1)-1; 

          MxV(row) = 0.0_real64
          do j=j1,j2
             col = matrix%colPtr(j)
             aij = matrix%aij(j)
             MxV(row) = MxV(row) + aij*vector(col) 
          end do
       end do         

    end function sparse_matvec

end module sparse_CSR

program test_sparse
  use sparse_CSR
  use iso_fortran_env
  implicit none

  real(real64) :: dense(3,3) = reshape(real([0,3,4,1,0,0,2,0,5],real64),[3,3]) 
  real(real64) :: vector(3) = real([1,2,3],real64)
  type(CSRMatrix) :: sparse
  real(real64) :: MxV(3)

  sparse = dense_to_sparse(dense)
  MxV = sparse_matvec(sparse,vector)

  print *, 'MxV = ',MxV

end program test_sparse
```

That will return:

```
 MxV =    8.0000000000000000        3.0000000000000000        19.000000000000000
```

Comment: Nice, good attempt to drag the question into this millennium! Just one comment, using ieee_value from the ieee_arithmetic intrinsic module is a clearer way of generating NaNs than transferring from the magic constant as you have here.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to learn how to implement this, you can use a sparse matrix library. E.g. SPARSKIT or suitesparse.

Comment: I was looking to learn how to implement it on the finite difference 2d. Thanks, i'm going to try those.