# Transferred efficient multiplication algorithm from MATLAB to Fortran does not match

Tags: algorithm, performance, matlab, fortran, memory-efficient

[Related to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73328183/efficient-way-of-multiplying-block-diagonal-matrix-by-vector) Thanks to the idea of @veryreverie, I was eventually able to multiply the block diagonal matrix by a vector with some modifications. (Matrix structure is at the end of post). However something is wrong. When I run the algorithm in MATLAB, there no issues.

The difference in direct multiplication and my result of `C'*x - bn` is within 1e-15 range due to machine addition non-associativity. However, when trying the same thing in Fortran it differs significantly, up to NaN value:

f90 code:

```
module RHS
implicit none
contains
subroutine RHS_eval(m,n,C,MM,q,LAP,BCterm,ADV,bn)

real*8, intent (in) :: x(:),C(:,:)
real*8, intent (out) :: bn(:)
integer*8 :: row, col
integer*8, intent (in) :: m,n

integer*8 :: offset, blkSz, blkShft, i
integer*8 :: xstart, ystart

bn = 0

bn(1:(m-1)*(n-1)) = bn(1:(m-1)*(n-1)) + x(1:(m-1)*(n-1));
bn(1:(m-1)*(n-1)) = bn(1:(m-1)*(n-1)) - x(m:(m-1)*n);

blkSz = m;
offset = (m-1)*(n);
blkShft = m-1;

do i = 1,(n-1)
    xstart = offset + blkSz*(i-1)+1;
    ystart = (i-1)*(m-1)+1;
    bn(ystart:ystart+blkShft-1) = bn(ystart:ystart+blkShft-1) - x(xstart:xstart+blkShft-1);
    bn(ystart:ystart+blkShft-1) = bn(ystart:ystart+blkShft-1) + x(xstart+1:xstart+blkShft);
enddo

end subroutine RHS_eval

end module RHS
```

MATLAB code:

```matlab
n = 15; m = 10; 
x = (10*rand((m-1)*n+(n-1)*m,1));
bn = zeros((n-1)*(m-1),1);

bn(1:(m-1)*(n-1)) = bn(1:(m-1)*(n-1)) + x(1:(m-1)*(n-1));
bn(1:(m-1)*(n-1)) = bn(1:(m-1)*(n-1)) - x(m:(m-1)*n);

blkSz = m;
offset = (m-1)*(n);
blkShft = m-1;

for i = 1:(n-1)
    xstart = offset + blkSz*(i-1)+1;
    ystart = (i-1)*(m-1)+1;
    bn(ystart:ystart+blkShft-1) = bn(ystart:ystart+blkShft-1) - x(xstart:xstart+blkShft-1);
    bn(ystart:ystart+blkShft-1) = bn(ystart:ystart+blkShft-1) + x(xstart+1:xstart+blkShft);
end
```

We take the transpose of matrix `C` and multiply from RHS by a vector. There is no need to store the matrix since its structure is known.
[image: C]

Fixed a tiny bit, at early iterations it kinda works as expected, the number shown is the difference between matmul and my multiplication algo
`maxval(abs(bn - matmul(transpose(C),(x))))`

[image: Initial]

But starting at around 60th step starts to blow up

[image: Further]

This issue only happens for the case when `m` and `n` are not equal

Comment: Define 'significantly`. I'm not up on the code you're using, but it's quite possible that you're seeing a loss of precision due to differing data types

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular blows up to infinity at last iterations, 1e-3 at first iterations. dataTypes like real*8?

Comment: That's pretty significant. Sorry I can't add anything further.

Comment: Please include an example Fortran driver program so we can compile and check the code ourselves. You have compiled and run with all checks on?

Comment: If you'd like us to check your Fortran output, we need to see a complete Fortran program (see [mre]). It would also help clarity if you could avoid non-standard extensions, and remove declarations of unused local variables and useless semicolons.